# Case statement for additional column SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

if you have a column which has ABC and DEF like this:

```
Column ID
ABC           100
ABC           200
DEF           400
DEF           500
ABC           600
```

How do you then display the values of ABC in one column and the values of DEF in another column using SQL?

tables you can define as anything as only example

Comment: could u show the format of output u exactly want please?

Comment: What is the relationship between any ABC row and any DEF row? Do they share a key field you haven't shown? Please also tag the database you are using (e.g. Oracle) rather than the client/IDE; and it may be useful to know which version you're using too. I have no idea what the last sentence of your question means, incidentally.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a `case`:

```
select (case when col1 = 'ABC' then col2 end) as abc,
       (case when col2 = 'DEF' then col2 end) as def
from t;
```